# Nancy Mono Self-Host won't start on port 80

Tags: mono, nancy, raspbian

I have a self hosted Nancy application running on a Raspberry Pi and I can't get it to bind to port 80!

It works on port 81, 8090 and I even tried other "reserved" ports such as 443. They all work except 80.

I'm starting the app with sudo so it shouldn't be permissions and 81 works too.

```
sudo mono Lambda.Console.exe
```

The obvious culprit for this is that something else is using port 80 but I can't find out what it is. I have tried the usual;

```
netstat -ln - nothing is listening on port 80

telnet port 80 - connection is refused, suggesting nothing is listening
```

Does anyone have other suggestions? Can a process still be using the port? I'm stuck at this point.

Cheers

Dave

Comment: Any luck? I'm having same issue.

Comment: Hey sorry I've not managed to track down the issue yet, but still searching!!

Comment: Hey @JarrettV both the answers below fix the issue me me. Hope they work for you. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bug in Mono HttpListener I created pull request here: https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/891
Unfortunately I did not find workaround I will try to find robust workaround in Nancy since versions releases  are more frequent.

Comment: Hey David that sounds very promising. Great find. I'm just pulling your Nancy branch to start my own testing. Cheers Dave

Comment: I've just confirmed that your fix in Nancy is working for me. @david-karlas Thanks for finding this issue and solving it :-)

Answer (score 1):

I also found a work around for the issue that involves mapping port 80 to the port your Nacy app has actually bound too.

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth+ -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

You can undo this using the same command but using -D instead of -A and if you want to check it exists then use -C

Ideally it would be best to use the Nancy patch from @david-karlas or if it comes along a mono fix but if you have to use an old mono version with old Nancy version then this works too.